# Error using AxWebBrowser after disabling Refactor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, axwebbrowser, axhost

i was using AxWebBrowser (Microsoft WebBrowser // ieframe.dll) but when i decided to disable Refactor addon for Visual Studio (2017), its not working anymore at all.

And whenever i try to add an axWebBrowser to my form it throws this error:

[image]

PS: I tried to repair my VS install using the installer. The problem is still the same.